# Unable to launch docker log command from python script

Tags: python, python-2.7, docker

I am trying to launch a docker logs command from a python script. But it is giving me following error:

```
out:<open file '/data/output/docker_log.log', mode 'a' at 0x7f68292b7f60>
err:'logs: 1: logs: docker: not found\n'
```

Here is the code I used:

```
with open('/data/output/docker_log.log', 'a') as off:
    cmdArr = ['docker', 'logs', '--since', '9m', 'abc-service']
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmdArr, stdout=ofd, shell=True)
```

any idea what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What's `cmdArr` contain?

Comment: Edited the code.

Comment: If you're using the array form of `subprocess.Popen`, you don't need (or want) `shell=True`.

Comment: I have tried with and without that variable, although when I don't pass shell variable, I get No such file and directory error.